# How to read multiple files from directory and convert to matrix

Tags: r

I am new to R so this is probably a basic question. I have been given the script below but I want to automate it;

```
Temp=read.csv("RLD.csv", header=FALSE)
A<-as.matrix(Temp)
Temp=read.csv("304712F_1.csv", header=FALSE)
B<-as.matrix(Temp)
Temp=read.csv("304712F_2.csv", header=FALSE)
C<-as.matrix(Temp)
Temp=read.csv("308284F_1.csv", header=FALSE)
D<-as.matrix(Temp)
Temp=read.csv("308284F_2.csv", header=FALSE)
E<-as.matrix(Temp)
emd(A,B)
emd(A,C)
emd(A,D)
emd(A,E)
```

I have done the following to read all the csv files in the directory

```
FilesToProcess<-list.files(pattern="csv")
listOfFiles<-lapply(FilesToProcess, temp=read.csv(x, header=false))
```

How do I now get them as matrix? Then I need to do an end calculation comparing each one individually to the "RLD" sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
FilesToProcess <- list.files('path/to/the/directory/where/files/are', full.names = TRUE)
listOfFiles <- lapply(FilesToProcess, function(x){
  out = read.csv(x, header=FALSE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
  as.matrix(out)
})
```

Comment: That didn't work. It appears the files are not a matrix. ```emd(listOfFiles[1],listOfFiles[2])
Error in emdr(A, B, dist = dist, ...) : base must be a matrix
```

Comment: @TryAgain12, If you want a matrix, you should use `listOfFiles [[ 1 ]]` NOT  `listOfFiles[1]`. What you did gives you a list.

Comment: That worked. I thought I had tried the double brackets earlier and it didn't work. Now to figure out how to automate the EMD calculation step.